# Please explain how Ruby interprets numbers

Tags: ruby

When the following numbers are entered into irb, I get the following results:

```
50 #=> 50
050 #=> 40
030 #=> 24
005 #=> 5
```

Why does `050` equal `40` rather than `50`, `030 == 30`, `005 == 5`? What's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.

```
010 => 8
020 => 16
0777 => 511
```

Comment: What would be the best way to strip the leading zeros? Would creating a method converting Octal to Decimal be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: You may make your requirement clear and make another question. i.e. how those numbers are input? from form? from a file?

Comment: I understand that if this were from a file or form, I can simply convert the string to an integer, properly removing the leading zeros. Simply out of curiosity for my own sake, if these inputs were  of the Fixnums class? (not sure if I got that right..) rather than strings, what would be the best way to remove the leading zeros, and interpret them as decimal base rather than octal? I'm rather new at programming.

Comment: @user2684075 the numbers are converted at the parser level, once you have a Fixnum, the leading `0` is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Octal numbers. Not just in Ruby - most programming languages think that when you start a number with a zero, it's in base 8.

- 50 = 5 * 10
- 050 = 5 * 8